# Capture Twilio message history using Flex and webhooks

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using Twilio Flex and can see that the message history between the user and agent exists under the specific channel.

Now, I want to be able to capture this message history once the agent wraps up the chat. Initially, I was going to go with using a webhook such that Twilio calls my server with the channel SID on wrap up and I then fetch the messages for that channel. However, when I go to set a post-event webhook in the Flex chat service, it already points to a proxy.

Does this approach sounds sensible? How can I add another webhook endpoint for channel wrap up?

Thanks